# I suspect this integral has a closed form but I can't find it

Tags: definite-integrals, closed-form

$$\int_a^b \frac{\text{d}\eta}{\eta}\sin\left(A\eta^3\right)\sin\left(A(\eta-B)^3\right)$$

$$\int_a^b \frac{\text{d}\eta}{\eta}\sin\left(A\eta^3\right)\cos\left(A(\eta-B)^3\right)$$

where $a,b,A>0$ and $B\in \mathbb{R}$.

Can anyone help me with this? it seems to me there has to be a closed expression. I can find it for the case $B=0$, but not for any real $B$. For example, I know that:

$$\int_a^b \frac{\text{d}\eta}{\eta}\sin\left(A\eta^3\right)\cos\left(A\eta^3\right)=\frac16\left[\text{Si}(2A\,b^3)-\text{Ci}(2A\,a^3)\right]$$

Where $\text{Ci}$, $\text{Si}$ are the cosine and sine integrals.

Do you know how to get closed expressions for the integrals above when $B\neq0$? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Are Si and Ci really closed firms or just names for an integral, like $\Phi$ for the Gaussian ?

Comment: [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_a%5Eb+sin%28A+x%5E3%29sin%28A%28x+-B%29%5E3%29%2Fx++dx) does not know...

Comment: Let's put it like this, I am interested in knowing the expression of this integral in terms of Ci and Si